# Is it possible to read and parse graphiti diagram file in standalone app?

Tags: eclipse, diagram, graphiti

I am doing some research before putting my hand on a project.i need to implement an app that needs to read a diagram file generated by graphiti and parse the file as a standalone app without running in eclipse as plugin.

As I understand , graphiti is a plugin in eclipse,so lots of things are inited by eclipse , so is it possible? Could u plz point me to the right place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Graphiti needs an OSGI environment to operate. It is possible to read a diagram file in a standlone OSGI app without bringing up the UI. I have some sample code [here](https://github.com/e2point718/graphiti-examples/tree/master/com.github.e2point718.eclipse.diagramcmd) that starts an OSGI app and reads a diagram file. I guess the question is what you'd want to do with that diagram once the file is read - if your intention is to export that diagram to an image then you'd need the UI (an RCP app could do the trick) - sample code is [here](https://github.com/e2point718/graphiti-examples/tree/master/com.github.e2point718.eclipse.diagramview) which relies on a fix (eclipse bug id 423018) that just landed in graphiti 0.13.x